# Generate Mobile Map Cache from ArcObjects

Tags: arcobjects, mobile

As of ArcGIS 10, is there a way to generate a mobile map cache using ArcObjects?

This can be done in a stand-alone Python script:
http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//003z00000005000000.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would expect to see an assembly in arcobjects for mobile, but I don't.  Maybe you could use ESRI's visual studio tool to [generate an assembly](http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisengine/dotnet/462f5942-7928-44d6-b85b-56dc1a0d2ac4.htm) that wraps this gp tool.

Maybe when you run it from within VS in debug mode, you can watch what assemblies load then use the mobile assembly directly (assuming there is one).